# Normal distribution in R: Find the value of $x$ for $P(X=x) = c$ where $c$ is known

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a normal distribution with parameters $\mu=750$, $\sigma=260$. I'm interested in finding the value of $x$ that satisfies $P(X=x)=0.001$ for both sides of the tail. How would I go about doing that in R? I'm familiar with the `dnorm` and `qnorm` commands but I'm not sure how to implement them.

Eventually I'd like to expand this to distributions that aren't normal, so the more general the solutions are (ie: not using Z-score) the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any continuous random variable $P(X=x)=0$. But in your case if you are interested in mathematical view (not statistical)

$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-1(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
just find the inverse of the function

$$
{x}=\mu+\sqrt{-2\sigma^2\log({\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}f(x))}
$$

PS: this is just playing with an equation and there is no probability concept behind!

Comment: I believe that gives me the result from the cumulative, or $P(X<x)=.001$...

And yes, good point about how at any one spot technically the probability is 0.

Comment: user81182 -- it's not just some obscure technical objection; density is *not* probability. Leave R aside for the moment -- what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the two values of $x$ that will give me $f(x)=0.001$.

Comment: So if I want to generalize this to other distributions, I should start with the pdf and algebraically work my way back to find the inverse, as you did above with the normal. Correct?

Comment: yes. But PLEASE notice that this is just mathematics and you cannot find probability density function in a single point  except you have a discrete RV.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to invert the cumulative distribution function, NOT the density.  I think you want to know the value of x such that P(X <= x)  = 0.001, and the value of x such that P(X <= x) = 0.999. If I am correctly discerning what you really want, then the answer to which I am commenting is NOT what you want. I believe part of the confusion is because little f, i.e., f(x), is traditionally used for probability density function, and capital F, i.e., F(X), is traditionally used for cumulative distribution function. I believe you want to deal with F(X), not f(x).